# Facebook app image posting problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am a facebook app developer and i usually create photo apps which posts random photos on user's wall.

But the problem is when my app posts image on user's wall , it shows like this :
" 3 March via Find your nickname "

I saw some other apps which posts image like :
" Adam found results using http://apps4urlife.com. "

My app shows like this :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6i2L8mw.png]

I want it to show like this :

[image]

Comment: can share your code snippet, you are using to post the picture ?

Comment: I am using facebook api to post the picture.. $photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST')

Comment: what all parameter you are passing?

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of post, you need to use `facebook-opengraph`, checkout the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/)
. you will need to create an object named `result` and associate an action `find` with the `result` object.

Comment: Thanks but This is not what i meant.. I have added the images above , please see...